# Do Azure Active Directory Identifies machine/IP/Network as well to login or there are any settings

Tags: azure, azure-active-directory

I am doing SAML SSO in my project , the scenario is I am preparing SAML Auth Request URL ,there is a login page where 2 radio buttons are there for Internal/External User ,In both radio case I have to prepare SAML Auth with the IDP Urls provided to me , I was able to prepare and it redirected me to Microsoft login page ,I been given credentials in that domain to login ,the issue is one person sitting in US tries to login with the credentials was successfully able to login ,got the SAML Response and it redirected him to Redirect URL ,when I took the same credentials of him ,tries to login from my machine ,I got error like you are not authorized ,I been confused what does happen ,we are using the same credentials but machine is different ,Is there any settings in Azure Active Directory which checks NETWORK/Machine/IP as well ?

Answer (score 1):

Yes, they do sign-in risk detection based on many factors.
Location is one of them.
The one you probably hit is this one: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory/reports-monitoring/concept-risk-events#impossible-travel-to-atypical-locations.

It is impossible for this user to have traveled that large of a distance in such a short time,
so it gets flagged as suspicious and blocked.
I've had this happen as well when I signed in to an account through a VM in another continent.

It does learn typical locations over time though, so it might start working later.

> The algorithm ignores obvious "false positives" contributing to the impossible travel conditions, such as VPNs and locations regularly used by other users in the organization. The system has an initial learning period of 14 days during which it learns a new user’s sign-in behavior.

You should have your own user id :)

Comment: Thanks @junnas ,I will have a look on this ,need to go through this

Comment: @junnas .one more thing ,the same person tries to login from his local machine ,it did n't worked but from VM it did ? what could be the reason ?

Comment: No idea, logs in Azure AD could help. Your admin should take a look at them.